# Time for three people meeting at the same point again in a circular track

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
[(source website)](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3568#top)

In the above mentioned source, answer is given as $12$ hour.

**My Solution**

> A finishes each lap in $24/6=4$ hour
>  B finishes each lap in
>   $24/4=6$ hour
>  C finishes each lap in $24/8=3$ hour
>
> $\text{LCM(4,6,3)}=12$

But the above website does this as
LCM of $24/(6-4)$ and $24/(8-4)$ and obtains as $12$ hour

Could any one help me to understand whether my approach is right or not. Also what is the logic of the calculation mentioned above (in the site) or is it a wrong method? Or both these methods are right?

Comment: Note that the question does not ask "At what time will they all meet back at the starting point." They will first meet at the smallest value of $t$ for which the quantities $6t$, $4t$ and $8t$ differ by multiples of $24$ (in case such a $t$ might exist).

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, but both the approaches lead to same answer. is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Perhaps. Unless the rates are carefully chosen it could be the case that they never "all three" meet simultaneously. One might conjecture that if in case they ever do all three meet again then it must be at the starting point and that that will be the first time they meet as well. I do not know the answer to that off the top of my head. Perhaps you might look into it.

Comment: Suppose the track were 36 km. Which procedure would give the correct answer?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, if so, my method gives answer as 18 (lcm of 6, 9, 4.5).  The method shown in the site also gives the same (lcm of 18, 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us state a similar problem but get completely away from the particular numbers in the example.

Suppose they run at speeds of $1$, $3$ and $5$ km/hr respectively and that the track is $2$ km. Then after only $1$ hour they will all meet halfway around the track because $A$ will be only half-way, $B$ will have run one and a half times around the track and $C$ two and a half times around.

Using your method one would say that $A$ finishes in $2$ hours, $B$ in $\frac{2}{3}$ hours and $C$ in $\frac{2}{5}$ hours. The smallest whole multiple of these three numbers is $2$ although we know that the correct answer is $1$.

For the other method we divide the differences of the speeds into the distance. Two of the differences are $2$ and one is $4$. So we get $\frac{2}{2}=1$ and $\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$. The smallest whole multiple of these two numbers is the number $1$ which is the correct answer.

Comment: thanks, this is a great example for this problem. Now the difference is very much clear